# Should a guide on mining testnet ether be a community wiki?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, community-wiki

With [Comprehensive guide to mining testnet ether](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12160/comprehensive-guide-to-mining-testnet-ether) there were 3 close votes for it being off-topic.  It's hard to understand why it would not be on-topic.  How should it be dealt with?  Some options:

- remain as is
- convert to a community wiki now
- convert to a community wiki sometime in the future.  If so, when?
- close as some other reason?

Comment: _Just drive-by-commenting_: I noticed a lot of close-voting activity recently, some of them I did not agree with. However, for this site it's a good sign for activity and strong user base.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say **remain as is**. While I see that the question is not very specific, it's very well on-topic and an actual issue the users faces.

In general, I think it's good to have frequently asked questions featured on Stack Exchange. This could be a good example for a canonical question on *how to get testnet ether* with all options available and strings attached.

Finally, I don't think we should convert it to a community wiki post unless the author wants to.

Comment: Candidate for blog project?

Comment: @RobHitchens \o/

Answer (score 3):

As a matter of emerging policy, the Community Wiki setting has been all but deprecated. A user's **answer** should virtually *never* be forced to Wiki (to remove reputation or otherwise) unless it is explicitly set or requested by the author, and the ability to mark a **question** Community Wiki (with all its answer) has already been removed.

See [The Future of Community Wiki](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/)